# How to correctly join tables and return rest API object. [MYSQL + PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've got 3 table and need to make a nice smooth SELECT which could return me data from all of them.

This is how tables looks like:

**cases**

```
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |   id   |  case_id  |  country |         vin        |         
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |   22   |    9856   |    US    |  VF7S6NFZF56215577 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |   23   |    9857   |    GB    |  GF7S6NFZF56215579 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |   23   |    9858   |    US    |  VF7S6NFZF56215577 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

**calculations**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   calculation_id   |  case_id  |  totalcosts |       currency     |         
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         95         |    9856   |    78945    |         USD        |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         96         |    9856   |    12345    |         USD        |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         97         |    9857   |    23986    |         XTB        |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         98         |    9858   |    77896    |         USD        |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**positins**

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   calculation_id   |  case_id  |  text  | method |   guide | position_id     
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         95         |    9856   | textAB |   E    |    N/A  |     11     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         96         |    9856   | textAB |   E    |    N/A  |     22     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         96         |    9856   | textAC |   L    |    N/A  |     3      |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         96         |    9856   | textAD |   E    |    Y    |     8      |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |         97         |    9856   | textAE |   E    |    N/A  |     11     |    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how result should looks like (this is part of rest API so i will provide JSON)

```
[  
   {  
      caseId:9856,
      country:'US',
      totalcosts:12345,
      currency:'USD',
      positions:[  
         {  
            method:'E',
            guide:'N/A',
            positionId:22,
            text:'TextAB'
         },
         {  
            method:'L',
            guide:'N/A',
            positionId:3,
            text:'TextAC'
         }         {  
            method:'E',
            guide:'Y',
            positionId:8,
            text:'TextAD'
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      caseId:9858,
      country:'US',
      totalcosts:77896,
      currency:'USD',
      positions:[  

      ]
   }
]
```

**Eplenation of response:**

- cases: User always provide VIN number and query need to collect rest of data. Important thing is that there can be multiple cases for each vin. There should be provided always all of them.
- calculations: There can be multiple calculations for each case. Always just last one is important (the one with highest calculation_id for that case_id).
- positions: just extract data here

**What did I try:**

```
SELECT c.case_id, c.country, cl.totalcosts, cl.currency,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT po.text ORDER BY 1) AS texts,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT po.part_position_id ORDER BY 1) AS partIds,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT po.guidenumber ORDER BY 1) AS guideNumbers
FROM cases 
  LEFT JOIN calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id AND c.country = cl.country
  LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id AND cl.calculation_id = po.calculation_id
```

Idea behind this select is that I group all that data from positions table and then in my php file I will explode all of them by comma (`,`).

I think this is possible solution but really ugly one and I bet it is also not best for performance issues.

Can anyone think about better solution for this situation?
Thanks a lot!

p.s. All tables and query was simplify to keep this question clear. I'm sorry for possible typos

Comment: If you return JSON maybe you can use JSON_TYPE => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html and directly output JSON from you DB

Comment: That query do the job you want? Because if does then I dont see the ugly part. If doesnt I suggest you return your query without group_concat and build the json in a for .. loop in your php side

Comment: Hi @JuanCarlosOropeza if you return it without group_concat then i will not get all results from positions table, just one. Also I'm not sure if this select last calculation or first one

Answer (score 2):

This is made somewhat more complicated by the fact that you've not told us anything about the cardinality/foreign key constraints here e.g. how to handle number calculations

So I can't tell you what your query should look like.

I do agree that using GROUP_CONCAT() in this way is ugly.

Hence, using a simpler example of a 1:m relationship between a relation named 'header' and one named 'detail' ....

```
SELECT h.id, h.date, h.other,
d.type, d.unit_cost, d.quantity
FROM header h
LEFT JOIN detail d
ON h.id=d.header_id
WHERE ds.date
;

$output=array();
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($r);
    if (!is_array($output[$id])) {
       $output[$id]=array(
              'date'=>$date, 'other'=>$other, 
              'detail'=>array());
    }
    if ($type) {
       $output[$id]['detail'][]=array(
          'type'=>$type, 'unit_cost'=>$unit_cost, 
          'quantity'=>$quantity);
    }
}
print json_encode($output);
```

The `LEFT JOIN` and `if ($type) {` are needed if want to include header records which have no detail.